# Best way to organise Javascript code

Tags: javascript

How do you guys organise your javascript code?  I know that it is good practice to store the code in an external .js file and this is fine for code that is run in multiple pages but how do you organise if you have, say 20 pages, and only 1 of them uses a particular function.  Do you create a new external file for that 1 page or create the code inline?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do two things:

1. I put all my site's Javascript in one or more files;
2. I include that file or files on every page that uses any Javascript;
3. Those files are cached effectively such that they are only ever downloaded once (until they change); and
4. Pages call the functions they need from those external files.

If your site is one page then put it inline.

If your site is 20 pages and they all use a little bit of Javascript, put it all in one files, include it on every page and call the functions with inlien Javascript as necessary in each file.

I write about this and more in [Supercharging Javascript in PHP](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/05/supercharging-javascript.html). Sure it's PHP-specific but the principles are universal.

Basically every extra HTTP request is a problem. So if you have 20 pages each with a different Javascript file then that's a problem, even if those files are small. It's better to combine all that Javascript in one file, download it just once (with effective caching) and just use what you need.

To give you an example. External JS file contains:

```
function delete_user(evt) { ...}
function suspend_user(evt) { ... }
function unsuspend_user(evt) { ... }
```

One of your Web pages contains:

```
$(function() {
  $("#delete").click(delete_user);
  $("#suspend").click(suspend_user);
  $("#unsuspend").click(unsuspend_user);
});
```

This way you get an external JS that contains all your site's Javascript but none of it is actually used. Use comes from inline code in the pages. This way there is no overhead of having the larger JS file.

Whatever you do, don't put in ALL initialization in your Javascript file. I once made this mistake and put a huge $(function() { ... } function into the external file on the grounds that if the relevant IDs weren't in the page, nothing would happen. There ended up being enough of this code to add nearly half a second to the page load time (and the site wasn't *that* big).

Comment: I like the idea of putting all functions in JS and calling from inline, makes sense! How would you then cope with jQuery event handlers, would you add the handler code inline and call external js method?

Answer (score 1):

The browser shouldn't redownload the javascript file once it has it, so I would put it into the single Javascript file. That saves another connection/request to the webserver, and it keeps the code in one place rather than having `script` tags and code in your HTML/JSP/PHP/etc files. I.e., it's more maintainable, and it's very little overhead to get the code (unless it's a 1000 line monster! but that's another problem entirely) even if it isn't used.

Not that I don't have `script` blocks in some files, for very very specialised cases. In the end it comes down to what you are happy with - but consistency across the project is what is most important, so don't have a one off script in one place, and then do something different elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

ALWAYS put JavaScript in a file external to HTML.  The problem with JavaScript that exists in page is that it typically exists in the global namespace, which could easily cause namespace collisions that makes code crash.

So, always put JavaScript in an external file.

With that said you should organize your code in an object-oriented manner.  Try to capture an entire application representing a single point of execution to a single named function.  Always write your code using a single var command per function, which should go at the top of the function, so that your code is easier to read.  Ensure all variables and functions are declared with a var command or they will into the global namespace, which is potential failure.  Put sections of execution of a giant function into smaller child functions, because this makes code easier to maintain when you can point to a particular named block when debugging or writing enhancements.

Also, always run your code through JSLint to verify syntax accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a small amount of code I don't believe it is worth the effort to split it up.

Depending on how much JS you have, consider a build process that can concatenate your separate JavaScript files into one, minified single download.

YUI is incredibly modular. They have a 'core' set of includes and then you can supplement these with the widgets you actually use. For instance, I have no interest in using their file uploader widget so never include the JS for it.

Cache the JS for a date far in the future. If you need to make a change, append a version stamp to the end of the SRC attribute, i.e. my-code.js?v=91

Use namespaces to avoid polluting the global scope. Again, YUI is very organised in this regard - see the YAHOO.namespace() function.

Answer (score 0):

For only one function it would be better to code inline. 
I won't include a 100KB Util script file for just calling a Trim function inside it.

If the file is already cached then it won't be a problem if you refer this in a page which calls only one function inside the file.

Answer (score 0):

I would say put it in an external file.  Chances are you will need to add new functions to it anyway, but also, from an SEO point of view, keeping it in an external file is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

If I have a choice, I put the JS functions in external files, but not all in one file. Cache or no cache, I group files by their functionality and organize them similar to Java packages. If I have an utility function, say something generic like `trim()`, that goes to the top most JS file and all pages can use it. If I have something specific to a part of the site (unused in other parts) that goes in something like a sub-package, just for that specific part… and so on.

Of course you must use common sense so you don’t overdo it, and have let’s say a function per JS file. If you have fine grained JS files, that will affect you when your site evolves and you find yourself moving functions from sub-packages to an upper package or the other way around. I think one parent utility JS and one JS per site functionality should, most of the times, suffice.